# entity-framework no context menu in VS2012

Tags: entity-framework

I've installed EntityFramework from VisualStudioGallery to VS2012 but when I mouse over the project, there is NO "Entity Framework" context menu available.

The menu "Manage NuGet Packages" is available over "Resources" and EF Package is installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused. For add a Entity Model Desing file you need RMouse in the project, select add new and select the option "data" and after select "**Ado.Net Entity Data Model**".

If you want the option "Entity Framework" in the menu of RMouse you maybe are talking about Entity Power Tools, and for that you need to get that plugin [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

The Entity Power Tools will to enable the option "**Entity Framework**" in the main menu of the RMouse and is for generate POCO class based in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to intall the 2012.2 update http://www.asp.net/vnext.